# wifi failled connection with yun and after upgrading openwrt

Tags: wifi, arduino-yun, wireless

I recently bought an arduino yun. When trying to connect to the router following the procedure in https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoYun#toc14. After the Configure & Restart, the Arduino network shut down after a few moments but it wasn´t linked to my router.

After reading a bit about it in the internet, i upgraded it following https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/YunSysupgrade. As i found that the firmware version 1.5.3 was from 2014 https://github.com/arduino/openwrt-yun/blob/master/ChangeLog, and as Reflashing the OpenWrt-Yun image on the Yún would void warranty, i proceeded by http://nootrix.com/software/upgrade-arduino-yun-openwrt/. Everything occured as detailled there.

However now, when i turn on the yún, none network appear and the WLAN LED doesn't blink.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Find out if the Linux system is running. Maybe you mistyped your WiFi password.
Try the Following:

- connect via Ethernet check your router to see if the Yun request an IP via DHCP
- If unsuccessful connect via USB and install this [sketch](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/YunSerialTerminal) to see if you get a command prompt maybe your network settings are messed up

Still no success?

- Press the WiFi reset button for at least 30 seconds to do a reset to
  factory defaults.